# How to loop over big dataframe in batches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pretty big dataframe of about 1.5 million rows and I am trying to execute the code below into batches of 10,000. Then append the results into the "dataset" dataframe. One of the columns, 'subjects' is structured really weird so I had to clean it up but it takes a long time to process. That's why I want to use the k=10,000 batch. Thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

```
reuters_set = reuters_set.loc[reuters_set['subjects'].str.contains('P:')]

reuters_set.shape[0]

1590478

reuters_set.subjects.iloc[33] #Example of data in column that needs to be processed

['B:1092', 'B:12', 'B:19', 'B:20', 'B:22', 'B:227', 'B:228', 'B:229', 'B:24', 'G:1', 'G:6', 'G:B1', 'G:K', 'G:S', 'M:1QD', 'M:AV', 'M:B6', 'M:Z', 'R:600058.SS', 'N2:ASIA', 'N2:ASXPAC', 'N2:BMAT', 'N2:BMAT08', 'N2:CMPNY', 'N2:CN', 'N2:EASIA', 'N2:EMRG', 'N2:EQTY', 'N2:IRNST', 'N2:LEN', 'N2:MEMI', 'N2:METWHL', 'N2:MIN', 'N2:MINE', 'N2:MINE08', 'N2:MTAL', 'N2:MTAL08', 'N2:STEE', 'P:4295865030']

dataset = []

k = 10000
ct=0    

# Testing the first 10,000. It takes really long after this value...

bk = reuters_set.iloc[0:k]
bk.reset_index(inplace = True)
bk['id'] = np.arange(bk.shape[0])

bk['N2'] = ''
bk['P']  = ''
bk['R']  = ''

for index, row in bk.iterrows():
    a = [i.split(':') for i in ast.literal_eval(row['subjects'])]
    b = pd.DataFrame(a)
    b = b.groupby(0, as_index = False).agg({1:'unique'})
    dict_code = dict(zip(b[0], b[1]))
        if 'N2' in dict_code.keys():
            bk.loc[bk['id']== index, 'N2'] =  str(dict_code['N2'].tolist())
        if 'R' in dict_code.keys():
            bk.loc[bk['id']== index, 'R' ] =  str(dict_code['R'].tolist())
        if 'P' in dict_code.keys():
            bk.loc[bk['id']== index, 'P' ] =  str(dict_code['P'].tolist())
```

Comment: `iterrows()` is generally quite slow, so that certainly can't be helping. Can't these operations be vectorized? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why? You process data in chunks when you cannot store it all in memory. But given that you have access to the entire DataFrame your goal should be to use a vectorized calculation, or optimized pandas methods, on the **entire** DataFrame.

Comment: looping over dataframe rows using itertuples() - iterrows() are quite slow. Consider using built-in functions without using loop or vectorize it using numpy.